# Microsoft Graph API - /drive/root/children always empty, even though I have files in my onedrive

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to [List Children](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/item_list_children) by [Getting access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)

I have built my URL as you would expect:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/edffcd1c-e5b2-42f2-b554-XXXXXXXXX/drive/root/children

Where `edffcd1c-e5b2-42f2-b554-XXXXXXXXX` is the user ID of whom I'm trying to list the files.

Yet when I call this I get an empty result every time:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drive/root/children",
    "value": []
}
```

Why is that?

UPDATE: It seems that this API is only returning files from the **Sharepoint** account... not the OneDrive account. I already have access to the Sharepoint files from the Sharepoint API's themselves. Is there a way to get OneDrive files from the Microsoft Graph API?

This URL https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm seems to state that we *should* be able to do this.

Comment: Have you attempted to use the `userPrincipalName` instead of `id`? For example: `/users/rgregg@contoso.com/drive/root/children`.

Comment: yeah that just makes it throw an error "resource not found for the segment". I talked to microsoft ... this api only supports sharepoint files through app-only user i guess. total garbage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a typo in the User:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/edffcd1c-e5b2-42f2-b554-XXXXXXXXX/drive/root/children`

was supposed to be

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('edffcd1c-e5b2-42f2-b554-XXXXXXXXX')/drive/root/children`

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to get OneDrive files from the Microsoft Graph API?

Yes, there is: you must use the scope `Files.Read.All` or `Files.ReadWrite.All`

then, your requests to `/drive/root/children` will no longer return an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this endpoint
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children

and pass authorization header Bearer Token

Comment: isn't my existing answer easier because then you can just supply the user ID and get the User's files with the same service account token? Either way thanks for the details.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things:

1) First check if the user has given the permission for

> Files.Read.All or Files.ReadWrite.All

2) The following endpoint didn't work for business account

> /drive/root/children

I changed it to

> /drives/{drive_id}/root/children

and it worked fine. Please check.